Syntax error by using alter table statement
I am trying to change column name in SQL but it is showing me error
query
alter table cust
rename column first name to first_name(30) ;

error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "name"LINE 2: rename column first name to first_name(30) ;
^SQL state: 42601Character: 38

Kindly check what we can do in this case to remove error.

Which dbms are you actually using? MySQL, SQLite and Oracle all have different ALTER TABLE syntax.

What's first_name(30) supposed to mean?

You're trying to remame column first name (Note the space)
to first_name.
first name is not a valid column name because it contains the space.
Please double-check what actual column you have in this table.
If your table column name is containing a space, then you need to wrap it withing "", like "first name"

It's a valid name, but needs to be delimited.

You are trying column name with spaces, that can be the issue. Try with double quotes.
ALTER TABLE cust
RENAME COLUMN "first name" TO first_name;

